# Simplify lookup aggregation stages

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Given this document, I'd like to lookup the references of `context` and `selection` and replace the `objectId` with a property, and then turn it into an object. My code below works (even though I have my doubts regarding corner cases for `$zip`).

There has to be a more simpler syntax than what I have right now?

PS: The `reporting` array usually have up to 7 items.

**document**

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "644f8d5c8e21a16d59ce7c9a"
  },
  "reporting": [
    {
      "context": {
        "$oid": "613f072dc1ebeca3f09bf6fe"
      },
      "custom": null,
      "selection": {
        "$oid": "62188cfd9f008079d3d63b6b"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**pipeline**

```
[{
    $addFields:
      {
        reporting: {
          $map: {
            input: "$reporting",
            in: {
              k: "$$this.context",
              v: "$$this.selection",
            },
          },
        },
      },
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "ReportingContexts",
      localField: "reporting.k",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "contexts",
      pipeline: [
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 0,
            k: "$keyName",
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "ReportingTreeNodes",
      localField: "reporting.v",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "treeNodes",
      pipeline: [
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 0,
            v: "$referenceId",
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  {
    $addFields:
      {
        reporting: {
          $zip: {
            inputs: ["$contexts", "$treeNodes"],
          },
        },
      },
  },
  {
    $addFields:
      {
        reporting: {
          $arrayToObject: {
            $map: {
              input: "$reporting",
              in: {
                $mergeObjects: {
                  $map: {
                    input: "$$this",
                    in: "$$this",
                  },
                },
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
  }]
```

**result**

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "644f8d5c8e21a16d59ce7c9a"
  },
  "reporting": {
    "operationId": "A110",
    "orderId": "000004457242",
    "structureId": "A000097",
    "activityType": "0000044572420400"
  }
}
```

Comment: _`localField: "reportingTemplate"`_ Where does this come from?

Comment: Ahhh. Sorry - I have pasted the wrong part of the pipeline. Will update!

Comment: Is there a guarantee that `"$lookup"` will return an array ordered identically to the `"localField"` array values?  If not, couldn't this query _"mis-pair"_ the results?

Comment: That is one of my concerns. There has to be a more simple way of doing this "double" lookup.

Comment: Can you please share some sample data for `ReportingContexts` and `ReportingTreeNodes`?

Comment: Here's a [mongoplayground.net mockup](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-3cxwxZihJG) of your data and pipeline.  Close enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood correctly, here's one way to do it insuring that the *pairing* is done properly.

```js
db.Reporting.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "ReportingContexts",
      "localField": "reporting.context",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "contexts",
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$project": {
            "_id": 1,
            "keyName": 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "ReportingTreeNodes",
      "localField": "reporting.selection",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "treeNodes",
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$project": {
            "_id": 1,
            "referenceId": 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "reporting": {
        "$arrayToObject": {
          "$map": {
            "input": "$reporting",
            "as": "report",
            "in": {
              "k": {
                "$getField": {
                  "field": "keyName",
                  "input": {
                    "$first": {
                      "$filter": {
                        "input": "$contexts",
                        "as": "context",
                        "cond": {"$eq": ["$$report.context", "$$context._id"]}
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              "v": {
                "$getField": {
                  "field": "referenceId",
                  "input": {
                    "$first": {
                      "$filter": {
                        "input": "$treeNodes",
                        "as": "treeNode",
                        "cond": {"$eq": ["$$report.selection", "$$treeNode._id"]}
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/86PpE5ki2ui).